# Variogram and STSDF object with monthly data (Updated)

Tags: r, time, time-series, geospatial, temporal

I have monthly data spread over 2 years. Some of my sites do not have data for every month so I have used an STSDF with an index containing spatial ids and temporal ids 1:24 (one for each month)

```
 DATE.formatted<-as.yearmon(2007 + seq(0, 23)/12)
 COOR.formatted=SpatialPoints(COOR,proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
 datST = STSDF(COOR.formatted, DATE.formatted,  dataframe, index)
 var.st.o=variogramST(O18.res~ 1,
                 datST,tlags=0:24, 
                 na.omit=TRUE)


 spatialVgm = vgm(psill=1.5,sp, range=575, nugget=0)
   temporalVgm=vgm(psill=1.5,t, range=24, nugget=0)
 separable<-vgmST("separable", space = spatialVgm, time =      temporalVgm, sill = 3) 
 fit.ssum.o=fit.StVariogram(var.st.o,  separable,fit.method = 8)

 #krige the data
 pred.o <- krigeST(O18.res~1,
              data=datST, newdata=datST,
              modelList=fit.ssum.o)
```

When I try to krige the data I get this error:

Error in UseMethod("units") :
no applicable method for 'units' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"

I've tried using different model types but to no avail. I was using a different STSDF object, but I got the same error, I thought it might be something to do with the second object, so I just tried to predict using my original STSDF object.
I'm wondering if it might be something to do with the time and  endTime slot?

```
 Slot "time":
          timeIndex
 Jan 2007         1
 Feb 2007         2
 Mar 2007         3
 Apr 2007         4
 May 2007         5
 Jun 2007         6
 Jul 2007         7
 Aug 2007         8
 Sep 2007         9
 Oct 2007        10
 Nov 2007        11
 Dec 2007        12
 Jan 2008        13
 Feb 2008        14
 Mar 2008        15
 Apr 2008        16
 May 2008        17
 Jun 2008        18
 Jul 2008        19
 Aug 2008        20
 Sep 2008        21
 Oct 2008        22
 Nov 2008        23
 Dec 2008        24

 Slot "endTime":
  [1] "2007-02-01 UTC" "2007-03-01 UTC" "2007-04-01 UTC"
  [4] "2007-05-01 UTC" "2007-06-01 UTC" "2007-07-01 UTC"
  [7] "2007-08-01 UTC" "2007-09-01 UTC" "2007-10-01 UTC"
 [10] "2007-11-01 UTC" "2007-12-01 UTC" "2008-01-01 UTC"
 [13] "2008-02-01 UTC" "2008-03-01 UTC" "2008-04-01 UTC"
 [16] "2008-05-01 UTC" "2008-06-01 UTC" "2008-07-01 UTC"
 [19] "2008-08-01 UTC" "2008-09-01 UTC" "2008-10-01 UTC"
 [22] "2008-11-01 UTC" "2008-12-01 UTC" "2008-12-31 UTC"
```

Comment: Update, I've tried changing the date to a yearmon object but now I get a new error: Error in UseMethod("units") : 
  no applicable method for 'units' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Update: I think I've found the problem. It seems that I can't use yearmon format for my dates. I changed it back to Date format with all dates 15th of the month, and it is working now. I'll leave the question up in case anyone else has the same issue